# Unlocking Portable External SSD on linux

Tags: ssd

I installed linux Ubuntu on my machine this week. I am completely new to linux. I have backup data from my previous windows OS on Sandisk Extreme Portable SSD. When I connect drive on linux I get SSD unlocker.exe file. Since it is an .exe file I cannot use it on linux. How can I unlock this drive on ubuntu linux. I see no software download option on Sandisk website for linux.
[image]

Comment: The disk is encrypted with SanDisk SecureAccess which has no Linux support. Boot into Windows, decrypt it, and then it will be usable in Linux.